# How to deal with bossy/micromanaging colleague (postdoc)

Tags: postdocs, interpersonal-issues

I joined my current research group as a postdoc about one year ago. That project I was assigned to work on wrapped up, and I was assigned to work on a different project for this second year. This second project has been ongoing for a year (now it is in its second year out of three). A Ph.D. student and a postdoc have been working on this project. The postdoc in question is, in fact, a Ph.D. graduate from the same group and has been working on this topic for the past 5-6 years (5 years Ph.D. + 1-year postdoc). We essentially became postdocs at the same time.

This second project is on a short deadline requiring an experiment I am responsible for (my part) to be done by certain times within 3-4 months. The other student and postdoc have their parts to work on. I am working towards finishing my part within the deadline of the project.

It became apparent that the other postdoc sees himself as my manager in this project (despite us being on the same level). Essentially, he is trying to set weekly deadlines for my tasks and checks on my progress almost twice weekly through emails and messages. When I say I do not know how long a certain step will take (because this is research), he becomes pushy and tries to have me say some deadline or assumes a deadline himself. Example: I was thinking about learning some simulation tool that could help with the experiment, and he asked how long will it take me to learn. I said I do not know as I still had to read about it. He said to email some students who used it before and tell him how long. I refused because this is not how I operate, and I do not see the point of asking others how long it takes them to learn something. He proceeded to assume that ten days should be enough.

This has negatively affected me and reduced my productivity. I have my rhythm and work in a way incompatible with his.

Question: How do I deal with this? I want to draw boundaries. While I appreciate feedback on my work, I do not appreciate being micromanaged like this by an equal peer.

Last piece of info: Our PI is very much absent. When he does meet with us, he yells about how everything is late and that we should be faster. I am sure he would NOT be happy to be involved in this interpersonal discussion.

Comment: Have you tried explaining this situation to the colleague in question?

Comment: Not yet. I plan to talk to him next time he does this.

Comment: I hesitate to give the "Dilbert" answer. You probably don't want an enemy.